# Do we want to use a special font for IPA notation?

Tags: feature-request

In Japanese.SE they found [an issue with the rendering of some IPA](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/ipa-and-diacritic-rendering).

To solve this, they now have a special use where they surround IPA with double brackets or double slashes, and that text is then shown (in single brackets or slashes) in a different font, one more appropriate for rendering IPA.

Is this a feature we want on our site?

Comment: Does IPA for Portuguese have the same problems?

Comment: I don't know for sure, @Earthliŋ, but I bet that it does. The sound with IPA issues on that original question is the japanese ち, which is read "tchi"; I think it is the one used for Mirandese "[cochino](http://www.mirandadodouro.com/dicionario/traducao-mirandes-portugues/cochino/)", so my guess is that at least the Portuguese dialect of setentrional Portugal must use that sound.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I think we might use that "tch" IPA to describe the word "**cha**muscam" (~0m:05s) in this sound sample: http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/som4.html No?